# How to compute variance of error of a least squares model?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, linear-regression

A few weeks ago I was asked to solve the following homework problem. The answer was published after it was submitted. The problem is as follows:

Let $y=X\beta + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2I_N)$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $N=10$ and $\beta$ is a vector of length $3$. We are told $y'y=58$ and the normal equations are:
$$4\beta_1+2\beta_2-2\beta_3=4$$
$$2\beta_1+2\beta_2+\beta_3=7$$
$$-2\beta_1+\beta_2+6\beta_3=9$$

We are asked to find the least squares estimates of $\beta$ and $\sigma^2$.

I understand how to solve the system of equations to get $\hat{\beta}=[0,3,1]'$.

From here I have two questions:

How is it possible for $y'y=58$ when $y=[4,7,9]'$?

Using the formula from the textbook, $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{N-rank(X)}(y'y-\hat{\beta}'X'y)$. When I compute this using $X$ as given in the normal equations I get $95/7$. However when I transform $X$ to reduced row echelon form, the formula results in $\hat{\sigma}^2=4$ which is the correct answer. So my question on this front is, why is it necessary to transform $X$ to RREF, or is there some other aspect that I am missing here?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The normal equation is $(X^TX)\beta = X^Ty$.  So $(4, 7, 9)'$ is $X^Ty$, not $y$. In fact you are told $N = 10$, so $y$ must be a vector of length $10$, which could not be $(4, 7, 9)'$.

Comment: Thank you @Zhanxiong, I think that gap in my understanding must be the source of my issues during this problem.

Comment: By the way I don't think the given conditions you put are enough to determine $\hat{\sigma}^2$. Did you miss anything?